# Jquery val() doens't work on hidden fields

Tags: jquery, input, internet-explorer-7

I have a weird problem with some jQuery code for a project I'm working on. I have to make a backend system, but it has to work in IE7 for the customer care department of the company.

I have a image plugin in the system where you can recrop te images.
When you do that, this piece of code will be generated

```
<input id="imagewidth_large" type="hidden" value="640" name="imagewidth_large">
<input id="imageheight_large" type="hidden" value="360" name="imageheight_large">
<input id="imagewidth_xlarge" type="hidden" value="640" name="imagewidth_xlarge">
<input id="imageheight_xlarge" type="hidden" value="270" name="imageheight_xlarge">
<input id="imagewidth_list" type="hidden" value="360" name="imagewidth_list">
<input id="imageheight_list" type="hidden" value="270" name="imageheight_list">
<input id="imagewidth_grid" type="hidden" value="270" name="imagewidth_grid">
<input id="imageheight_grid" type="hidden" value="270" name="imageheight_grid">
<input id="imagewidth_grid_wide" type="hidden" value="230" name="imagewidth_grid_wide">
<input id="imageheight_grid_wide" type="hidden" value="135" name="imageheight_grid_wide">
<input id="orgwidth" type="hidden" value="1224" name="orgwidth">
<input id="orgheight" type="hidden" value="1632" name="orgheight">
<input id="orgpath" type="hidden" value="../../uploads/images/tmp/4e89d17443230.jpg" name="orgpath">
<input id="targetfile" type="hidden" value="../../uploads/images/tmp/4e89d17443230.jpg" name="targetfile">
<input id="crop_width" type="hidden" value="1224" name="crop_width">
<input id="crop_height" type="hidden" value="688.5" name="crop_height">
<input id="crop_rat" type="hidden" value="0.5228758169934641" name="crop_rat">
<input id="crop_x" type="hidden" value="0" name="crop_x">
<input id="crop_y" type="hidden" value="0" name="crop_y">
<input id="source" type="hidden" value="other" name="source">
<input id="croppedimage" type="hidden" value="" name="croppedimage">
```

This code are some reference fields (the plugin is an extended version of a smaller cropper)

The problem I have is that in my code you can press the recrop button that will open the recropper and generate some code. In this code he calls and sets values of these input fields.

The problem is that I can't set of read values of the fields.

```
$("#imagewidth_large").val();
```

This returns undefined

```
$("#imagewidth_large").val(500);
```

This doens't do anything.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an online example? Do you try to access the fields after `$(document).ready(function() {` or `$(function(){` ? What does `console.log($('#imagewidth_large').val());` returns?

Comment: Works fine in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/erAwE/.  Either it's working and you don't realize it or there's something else wrong in your code/HTML that you haven't shown us.  Are you generating more than one of these blocks of HTML?  You can't have multiple objects with the same ID.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML and jQuery code should be able to read the val().  Check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hZJVj/

Comment: Thanks The problem was that I also did some calls with an id before 
     
   

    #imagewidth_large

example

    $("#container #imagewidth_large").val()

It looks like it is not supported

Comment: @joose So is it currently working for you now? Maybe you have some broken JavaScript code that does not allow this part to execute. Can you post what you have for your other code?

Comment: I solved it. I just needed to replace $("#container #imagewidth_large").val() to $("#container").find("#imagewidth_large").val()